# Particle.js wrong height in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Link to the website:** [Click](http://213.241.89.163/bitcast_www/)

I was trying to quickly develop prototype website using Bootstrap and Particle.js as a background. The problem is that the height of the Particle.js background is limited to the height of the initial viewport of the screen.

You can clearly see it on the **Link** above when scrolling down.

Is it a CSS problem? I was troubleshooting it from some time, but have no clue what could be wrong.

Comment: We need to see the code. Please share the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `position: fixed` and `z-index: -999` at the *.particles-js-canvas-el* class. This will fix your problem.

Comment: Rookie mistake on my side - position: fixed is enough to fix this problem.